# Seeking algorithm other than Convex-Hull to avoid overlapping polygons

Tags: overlapping-features, algorithm

I want to draw polygons with no overlap, based on sets of points. If I use Convex Hull algorithm to deduce the boundary polygon, it's pretty obvious that the resulting polygons WILL overlap. Is there a better algorithm; a way to includes vertices which are NOT to be overlapped?

I am using https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java

I am not using GIS software but rather I want/need to integrate this work into a software release pipeline.

[image: Two polygons and a set of points one polygon was derived from]

Comment: you should use concave hull, esri probably has an algorithm for that.

Comment: Complimenting @Gery I would suggest you explore the Euclidean Allocation tool in ArcMap and if you need the data as vector your can easily convert the result  back to vector.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Concave Hull indeed does a lot better, however still with overlaps as I can tell - but that might be a K-selection thing I need to tweak. Euclidean Allocation looks pretty awesome, except I can't seem to find any algorithms for it and it appears to output raster data rather than vector data. @PolyGeo I am not using GIS software but rather I want/need to integrate this into a software release pipeline - so code of some sorts.

Comment: Outright code requests are off-topic here.  However, it's fine to ask questions that involve code as long as you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Comment: Try something with [Voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Comment: You need to integrate code, so use Postgres/Postgis, I think you can create a table of points with some sort of id columns to create different polygons. Once polygons are ready, just find the best fit between them (sure Postgis has ways to do this).